# Change the number of values in column

Tags: text-processing, awk

i have a file like this exemple:

```
2931
7895
6688
7895
2931
2931
6688
```

and I want to generate a file that contain this column and another one like this:

```
2931 1
7895 2
6688 3
7895 2
2931 1
2931 1
6688 3
```

Comment: How is colum 2 created?

Comment: What are your requirements, what have you tried, what problems have you encountered, what part(s) do you need help with, etc.? See [ask].

Comment: once you accepted an answer, please take your time (1~2 minutes) to add a simple clarification sentence into your question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the second column to be a unique number for each number in the first column (this is not clear in the question):

```bsh
$ awk '$2 = ( (k = key[$1]) ? k : key[$1] = ++n )' file
2931 1
7895 2
6688 3
7895 2
2931 1
2931 1
6688 3
```

This keeps track of the most recently assigned number in `n`, and the association between the first column and the generated number ("the key") in the associative array `key`.  The `k` variable is just a very tiny optimization to avoid de-referencing `key` twice in the case where a number exists for the data in the first column.

The logic:

Assign the key corresponding to `$1` to `$2` if it is other than zero (zero would mean uninitialized, and that `$1` had not been seen before).  If it is zero, assign the next available number to the key and then to `$2`

We don't need to explicitly `print` anything as the result of the expression will be non-zero.  Since the result of the expression is non-zero, it triggers the default action, which is to print the current (modified) record.

A slightly more generic variant of the command would use the full line as the value and then add a new column at the end, no matter how many columns were present in the input data:

```bsh
awk '$(NF+1) = ( (k = key[$0]) ? k : key[$0] = ++n )' file
```

---

Spelling out the code in equivalent "long hand" syntax:

```bsh
awk '
{
    k = key[$0]

    if (k != 0)
        newval = k
    else
        newval = key[$0] = ++n

    print $0, newval
}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to give a number to each new type of content, and then show that number on every lines with that same content?

```
awk '
    { if ( !seen[$0]++ ) {
       ind++ ; n[$0]=ind
      }
    }

    { print $0, n[$0] }
'
```

does what you need

Using [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton)'s suggestions it can be streamlined and made more "awk-like" as:

```
awk '
   ! ($0 in n) { n[$0]=++ind }
               { print $0, n[$0] }
'
```